# How should I write a results file using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch import process that has the following steps:

1. Read a file in a specific format
2. Save data for people, attributes and appointments (each file line can mean multiple inserts to multiple tables)
3. Write results file (primarily result of the read, but sometimes we can't process the read data into something we can coherently insert)

I currently have #1 in a set of Readers (one for each file format), and #2 and #3 in single Writer class. I feel that writing the results file should be a separate step from writing the data to the database, but I am not sure how to do this.

The options I know of are:

1. A step listener
2. A tasklet (?)

Are there other options and which option would be the way Spring Batch is designed for?

Comment: Is the results file a summary or...?   Can you provide more description on what is going in there?

Comment: The results file lists any issues with the import. So if data can't be read from one line, the results file would have a line for that. If, upon reading the data, I can't find a matching record in the database, the results file would have a line for that. There may be 0 results lines per input line (success) or multiple results lines per input line (multiple issues).

Comment: AKA a bad records file.  Ok.  In the processor/writer side of things, you can use listeners to handle that (The item is returned to the listeners on error so that you can persist it accordingly).  However, for reading errors, that's a different animal since we don't have an item to pass you (we weren't able to construct one...that's the problem).  In that case, you'd have to implement your own reader to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the current `ItemWriter` you have into two `ItemWriter`s and use a [`CompositeItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) as your chunk writer. This will delegate in the order you specify to the your two writers.

Comment: No need to worry about rollback; it's also guaranteed on files

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Good point, at least if you're using `FlatFileItemWriter`. I left that part out.